# nginx proxy and 404 redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxy, amazon-s3, nginx, http-status-code-404

Hi I would like configure my nginx server to proxy for amazon S3 and do something like mod_rewrite in apache - if proxy for amazon is 404 (file does'nt exist on amazon) then redirect me to my local file. It's possibble to do ?

This is my nginx config file:

```
upstream app{
 server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name www.mypage.com mypage.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mypagecom.log;

  location /photos{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://amazons3.mypage.com/photos;
    proxy_redirect off;
    error_page 404 /myerrorfile.jpg;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }


}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

to `location /photos`. Then your `error_page 404 /myerrorfile.jpg` will work even when the 404 error comes from the upstream server.